What is cache_invalidate and can we stop this for specific rules in Adobe?
I have noticed this in my website log files.

[2024-09-19T12:06:20.934406+00:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://www.abc.com/white-sauce-powder-knorr-54615500.html","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"TARGET_RULE_1_67190_1_0_6"}} []

What is this cache_invalidate doing and can we stop this invalidate process for specific identifier?
And also how to verify this identifier - "identifier":"TARGET_RULE_1_67190_1_0_6"

This call is the clearing of the Varnish, File cache and redis entries for all the pages and data that are affected by the target rule. This is widely used to know when the cache of each block needs to be cleared based on the entities that are related to it. The tag seems to be formed by <TargetRulePrefix>_<ruleId>_<EntityId>_<StoreId>_<CustomerGroupID>_<SegmentID>
When the target rule get it's changed applied, you will see this triggered to clear out the cache on the pages affected. This should clear the cache of any Product Detail Page, Product Listing Page and any other view that has this identifier related to it. This way, the next request will generate the cache again.
How to troubleshoot this, depends on what the rule does and how much products you are modifying with your target rule.
See this entry to understand how this is implemented at the block level.
If you need to know what this rules does: This allows to personalize how the related products, up-sells, and cross-sells are selected for an specific group of customers. You can see the documentation here

Thanks for your answer, i feel like i need more clear on this , so i will keep the answer open.

I've added documentation on what the rules does and where you can find it
